# 36 forks of evince vs. 36 instances of evince at once? Pros and cons?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pdf, dbus

For a research project in human learning and cognition we're writing a wrapper program/shell script with these objectives:

*(a) should launch 36 different pdfs at once.
(b) place them appropriately at different locations on the screen.
(c) should auto-flip to another page @ 1 page/s. If it reaches the end of the pdf, should load the next pdf in que.*

**Almost everything has been sorted out except which of these two approaches would be better and why?**

(A) If we use DBUS protocol to query  evince if it's on the last page, we can't have multiple instances of evince running 36 different .pdfs at once. So, we make 35(=36-1) forks of evince and change the identifiers in the code and name those newly compiled programs as evince1, evince2....upto evince35. The script would handle the 36 evince (evince, evince1, ...evince35) as different programs.

(B)We do away with the DBUS protocol and use some other method to auto-flip pages and launch 36 instances of evince running all at once.

**What would be the pros and cons of the two approaches?**

P.S.- I have a gut-feeling that opening 36 instances of a reader program and making it flip to next-page is just too much of work for the said program.

===============================

*PS- Please be kind to me, I'm not a programmer and forgive my ignorance. In a perfect world I'd not even need to know what the DBUS protocol is. :)*

Comment: hm.. i'm living in a perfect world, I don't know what is the DBUS nor evince... ;)

Comment: By the 'perfect world' comment I meant that since I'm not a programmer but a neuroscientist, I'd not need to this if everything was the way it should've been. BTW, evince is the default document reader on the largest no. of GNU/Linux distributions.

Comment: Please tag your question with Ubuntu as you are clearly referring to it. And while you are at it, you might want to consider deleting your question on SO and posting it in [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) which are geared towards general software questions like yours.

Comment: @Sami. The question is about better software design decision and has nothing to do with Ubuntu (or even evince. If you wish you can read it with 'Okular' substituted for 'evince').